# How to change a link href depending on a user's selected options (onclick)

Tags: javascript, php

(My apologies in advance—it's late and this might not be as clear as it should be. Also, JavaScript is NOT my forte at all!)

I have built a section of my site that layers multiple png files on top of each other (using divs) so my users can build custom avatars for their profiles. Everything looks to be working well, but now I am trying to wrap my brain around how I can save their selected options (I am not looking for help on saving their image, but instead for help on saving the selected variables).

For example: The user might choose head 3, body 17, eyes 5, nose 2, etc. I want to store their selected values in a MySQL table. I understand how to store the values, but I am stuck on the part of getting their values set in the link that will drive the PHP.

The form action for "Saving" their creation should reflect their selected options and change as the user changes them (if they change their mind). How do I go about changing each of the variables to reflect their selections?

The action might look something like this:

```
action="save.php?head=3&body=17&eyes=5&nose=2"
```

Let's pretend the user now changed their mind and wanted to go with head 82. When they select that option, the action should reflect that change:

```
action="save.php?head=82&body=17&eyes=5&nose=2"
```

Here is a sample of the code that I have so far that drives the image layering:

```
<a onclick="changeOuterwear(this)" id="15.outerwear/outerwear.09"><div style="background:url('../avatars/15.outerwear/thumb.outerwear.09.png') no-repeat center center;"></div></a>

<div class="avatar-12"><img id="outerwear" class="icon" border="0" /></div>

function changeOuterwear(thisDiv){
    document.getElementById('outerwear').src = "../avatars/"+thisDiv.id+".png"
}
```

To help clarify things a little (and hopefully show what I am having trouble verbalizing), I've thrown together a quick jsfiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/sheldond/mvf28rjp/2/

This is NOT using the images that I am using, so it's mighty ugly on the Fiddle. But at least you can see what I mean (hopefully)!

Comment: The question isn't very clear. The title says _link href_, but the question shows `action=`, which is part of a `<form>`. So is it a link or a form? If you're using a form, you can put the parmeters in hidden inputs rather than URL parameters.

Comment: Yup, I knew it wouldn't be too clear! Lol. I don't know why I was thinking it needed to be a form. It doesn't. Regardless, it's getting those parameters in the first place I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to create a form with input fileds of type hidden and than populate those fields with apropriate values using JavaScript. Than, you can serialize this this form and either send it using ajax with hidden POST parameters, or create a link to the form using serialized data (than you will be using GET method).

Here's the fiddle for you to check out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xdxfxwy/1/)

Also it is good for development purposes to change those `input` type from `hidden` to `text` so you can see clearly what is going on in them, and than, before going "live", changing them back to `hidden`.

Hers a sample HTML:

```
<form id="avatar" action="save.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="head" value="3" /> <!-- You can echo your PHP variable into the values here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="body" value="17" />
    <input type="hidden" name="eyes" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nose" value="2" />
</form>

<button id="change-head">Change Head</button>
```

And heres the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    serializeForm();

    $('#change-head').click(function(){
        $('input[name="head"]').val(82);
        serializeForm();
    });
});

function serializeForm() {
    var serializedOutput = $('form#avatar').serialize();
    $('#output').text($('form#avatar').serialize(serializedOutput));
    // you can also automatically update your form url
    $('form#avatar').attr('action', 'save.php?' + serializedOutput);
}
```

Comment: I've created a Fiddle to help illustrate where I am at: http://jsfiddle.net/sheldond/mvf28rjp/2/

Your solution is a step in the right direction, but I think my inability to explain things right now is misguiding you a little. Check out the Fiddle to see the "starting block".